# aws cfn-guard cannot validate referenced values

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I´m search for an option to also validate referenced values using cfn-guard in my pipeline, but haven´t found anything.

Basically, the example validation rule looks like this:

```
#Database
AWS::RDS::DBInstance StorageEncrypted == true
```

The Database template:

```
Parameters:
   StorageEncrypted:
    Default: true
    Description: Should the database storage be encrypted?
    Type: String

Resources:
 AuroraDBFirstInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      CopyTagsToSnapshot: true
      DBInstanceClass:
        Ref: DBInstanceClass
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref AuroraDBCluster
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineVersion: !Ref EngineVersion
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
      PubliclyAccessible: false
      StorageEncrypted: false     #1
      StorageEncrypted: !Ref StorageEncrypted  #2
      EnablePerformanceInsights: true
```

**#1** This would work

**#2** This will fail with the following message: *failed because [StorageEncrypted] is [StorageEncrypted] and the permitted value is [true]*

Does anyone know if it is possible to also validate referenced values as we´re using the throughout our templates?

EDIT: Found an open feature request: [Feature request](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-guard/issues/39) , but I leave this question open in case someone knows a workaround.

Comment: Can you show us what `StorageEncrypted` is?

Comment: StorageEncrypted is a parameter passed to the template. See my edited question. Thanks